# File Not Found Error When Programmatically Uploading File on Server

Tags: 2010, visual-studio

I created a web application for uploading files and associated metadata. When I test the solution on my laptop, it works without a problem (file gets uploaded and metadata is saved). When I try the deployed solution on the server, I get file not found error: 'Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\award.txt'. Through my application, I'm trying to upload a file from my laptop, so I'm not sure what is going on. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
            if (fileUpload.HasFile)
            {

                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        using (FileStream fs = (new FileInfo(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)).OpenRead())
                        {
                            SPList list = web.Lists["Awards"];

                            //Add the initial metadata. We will do an update for all lookup table values, as they need to be done after the record is created.
                            Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
                            ht.Add("wfRecipientRank", ddRanks.SelectedValue);
                            ht.Add("wfRecipientName", txtRecipientName.Text);
                            ht.Add("APFT", rbPassedApft.SelectedValue);
                            ht.Add("HeightWeight", rbMeetHtWt.SelectedValue);
                            ht.Add("Posthumous", rbPosthumous.SelectedValue);

                            SPFile file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUpload.FileName, fs, ht, false);
                            SPListItem item = file.Item;

                            //Get the lookup field values
                            SPList lookupList = web.Lists["AwardType"];
                            int awardTypeId = GetItemId(ddAwardTypes.SelectedValue, lookupList);
                            SPFieldLookupValue awardTypeLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();

                            if (awardTypeId > 0)
                                awardTypeLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(awardTypeId, ddAwardTypes.SelectedValue);

                            lookupList = web.Lists["AwardReason"];
                            int awardReasonId = GetItemId(ddAwardReasons.SelectedValue, lookupList);
                            SPFieldLookupValue awardReasonLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();

                            if (awardReasonId > 0)
                                awardReasonLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(awardReasonId, ddAwardReasons.SelectedValue);

                            lookupList = web.Lists["Organization"];

                            MilitaryUnit organizationSelected = null;
                            SPFieldLookupValue organizationLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();

                            if (Session["OrganizationSelected"] != null)
                            {
                                organizationSelected = (MilitaryUnit)Session["OrganizationSelected"];
                                int organizationId = GetItemId(organizationSelected.uic, lookupList);

                                if (organizationId > 0)
                                    organizationLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(organizationId, txtOrganization.Value);
                            }

                            item["Organization"] = organizationLookupValue;
                            item["AwardType"] = awardTypeLookupValue;
                            item["AwardReason"] = awardReasonLookupValue;
                            item.Update();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are opening a stream server side. This just won't work because the file does not exist server side. The FileUpload control has a FileBytes property that you can use.

```
//Off the top of my head I can't remember if ServerRelativeUrl contains a trailing slash so you might need to add one.
string fileUrl = string.Format(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl{0}, fileUpload.FileName); 

SPFile file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, fileUpload.FileBytes);
```

I know this is code example short and sweet but I think it will very easily get the point across.

This is how I usually do it, but if you really want to use a stream there is [FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx).